# Average day of month from list of dates in PHP

Tags: php, date, average

I'm trying to find the average date and guess the next one.

The input is a list of dates that looks like this:

```
 $completeDate = array(
     '2015-04-13T00:00:00-0800',
     '2015-03-20T00:00:00-0800',
     '2015-02-17T00:00:00-0800',
     '2015-01-10T00:00:00-0800'
 );
```

I'm trying to scan a list of x amount of dates, and output an average of the dates overall.

So in the above example I think the output would be `2015-5-15` is expected average date.

How would I tackle this?

Comment: Do you mean the median date maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking for the average of those dates you can simply get the day of the year for each of those dates, average them out, and use that date:

```
$completeDate = array(
    '2015-04-13T00:00:00-0800',
    '2015-03-20T00:00:00-0800',
    '2015-02-17T00:00:00-0800',
    '2015-01-10T00:00:00-0800'
);

$first = null;
$last = null;
foreach($completeDate as $date) {
    $dayOfYear = (new DateTime($date))->format('z');
    if (is_null($first)) {
        $first = $last = $dayOfYear;
    }
    else {
        if ($dt < $first) {
            $first = $dayOfYear;
        }
        if ($dt > $last) {
            $last = $dayOfYear;
        }
    }
}
$avg = round(($first + $last) / 2); 
$averageDate = DateTime::createFromFormat('z', $avg);
echo $averageDate->format('Y-m-d'); // 2015-02-26
```

[Demo](https://eval.in/296932)

If your looking for the average of the day of the month for the dates in that array and then use that day of the next month, you just need to average out the days of the month and then use that with the next month:

```
$completeDate = array(
    '2015-04-13T00:00:00-0800',
    '2015-03-20T00:00:00-0800',
    '2015-02-17T00:00:00-0800',
    '2015-01-10T00:00:00-0800'
);
$month = 0;
$days = 0;
foreach($completeDate as $date) {
    $dt = new DateTime($date);
    $month_num = $dt->format('n');
    if ($month_num > $month) {
        $month = $month_num;
    }
    $days += $dt->format('j');
}
$avg = round($days / count($completeDate));
$date = new DateTime(sprintf('%d-%01d-%01d', $dt->format('Y'), ++$month, $avg));
echo $date->format('Y-m-d');  // 2015-05-15
```

[Demo](https://eval.in/296935)

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I do believe this is what I'm looking for though. Taking the average day of the month and then applying it to the next month. Thanks for the quick reply with 2 different answers too.